# typescript not loading at runtime

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a web app that was started in VS2015 using Angular 2 and was working for as far as it went. I upgraded it to VS2017 and had to make a few changes, but in the main all seems ok. I don't receive any compile time errors. During the run phase, when I'm attempting to load a page, the page doesn't fully render and I don't get any real errors on screen. I'm using I.E.11 and when I look in the console I get the following error:

`Error: Syntax error
  Evaluating http://localhost:42413/app/app.module.js
  Evaluating http://localhost:42413/app/main.js
  Loading app`

the Two files in question are in the place expected and no code has changed around these files since I did the port.

In my main.ts file I have:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

and in app.module.js I have:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AgentDetailsComponent } from './recruiter/agent-details.component';

@NgModule({
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule

],
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AgentDetailsComponent

],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The error occurs on the second line of main.ts: `import { AppModule } from './app.module'` Setting breakpoints it does not get to the first line in this file. Stepping the JS files. It first goes through the register-loader.js file which calls evaluate.js. It then fails in the evaluate method. There is a huge stacktrace, but basically it's erroring in the files that are under node_modules.

If I run in a chrome browser I receive the an error from zone.js stating that it cannot load http://localhost:42413/agent-details.component.html.

Within my projects wwwroot directory this component sits in my app\recruiter folder.

In the app.module.ts folder it is referenced as :

import { AgentDetailsComponent } from './recruiter/agent-details.component';

and the above line hovering over ./recruiter/agent-details.component shows the correct path in the tooltips.

In Chrome itself the error seems to occur whilst performing `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);` declared in main.ts

my agent-details.component.ts file has:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { ICountry } from '../services/interfaces/country';
import { RecruiterService } from '../services/recruiter/recruiter.service';

@Component({
selector: 'agent-details',
templateUrl: 'agent-details.component.html',

providers : [RecruiterService]
})
export class AgentDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
private countries: ICountry[] = [];
private errorMessage: string;

constructor(private recruiterService : RecruiterService) {

} 

getCountries() {
    this.recruiterService.getCountries().subscribe((countries: ICountry[]) => this.countries = countries);
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCountries();

}
}
```

Comment: i think the typescript transpilation to js is not ready in the moment your try to load in your html. so the file is not available. i don't use vs so i can't help more. but perhaps it helps you to figure out the problem

Comment: does it work in other browsers ?

Comment: Not tried it in other browsers yet, but it worked fine before I changed from VS2015 to VS2017

Comment: @mtizziani I've managed to get a bit further tracking the error. Don't know if my update might offer anymore thoughts.

Comment: @n00dl3 I have installed chrome and it seems to give a path error, but why I'm not sure. These have not changed since the upgrade. It's as if Zone is ignoring my default path.

Comment: can you show us the `@Component({...})` part of `AgentDetailsComponent` ? Are you using sytemjs or webpack ? maybe angular-cli ?

Comment: @n00dl3 in my tsconfig.json file I make use of commonjs. I am not using webpack. in my agent-details.component.ts file (see above I've changed main question at bottom). Resides under the html file of the saqme name holding the template.

Comment: @n00dl3 Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Not sure why as I've mentioned a few times prior to porting all worked fine. In the `agent-details.component.ts` file I have had to declare the FULL path for the templateUrl so that it now becomes `app/recruiter/agent-details.component.html` not sure why I now have to do this, but it worked.

Comment: @n00dl3 Just changed back to I.E.11 and it still fails with the same error, but is ok in chrome